# Key properties file for digital signature in Java

Tags: java, encryption, properties, key, sign

I'm trying to sign a PDF file with a digital signature and to do this it's needed the data encryption.

I have to use a file that contains the encryption key properties to achieve this, but I really don't know what sorta of file it should be.

In an example I found it just says:

```
 /**
 * A properties file that is PRIVATE.
 * You should make your own properties file and adapt this line.
 */
public static String PATH = "c:/home/key.properties";
/** Some properties used when signing. */
public static Properties properties = new Properties();
```

But how can I obtain this "key.properties" file and how it should be like?

Comment: Is this Java? The please add the Java tag.

Comment: About loading Properties, see the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Comment: Thanks @Tichodroma , the tutorial was usefull but I still don't get how should I fill this file. I mean for encryption key, what kind of pair key/value should I add to my properties file? Should I fill a PASSWORD field, a PATH field and so on?

Comment: Perhaps try [the Java Tutorial on digital signatures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/gensig.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved reading the links:
[Properties java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

And:
[Digital signatures java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/gensig.html)